# m3u8 streaming just get audio when its playing iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, m3u8

I'm trying to play an streaming live video HLS in xcode5 iOS 7.1 i'm using the following code

```
NSURL *movieFile = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://streaming.tlsur.net:1935/blive/ngrp:balta.stream_all/playlist.m3u8"];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieFile];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
[player.moviePlayer play];
```

When i run this into the simulator it throw me this error

```
2014-08-01 02:48:23.598 StreamingTest[379:4303] RTCReporting: resolve from http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12
2014-08-01 02:48:23.845 StreamingTest[379:60b] _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
kind = 1;
new = 2;
old = 0;
```

If i run in my device it doesn't throw the _itemFailedToPlayToEnd but i only get audio

What was going on?

Comment: I am unable to play your URL in browser and iTunes. Are you sure this is a correct video stream format?

Comment: There is a problem with the streaming feed, it will be offline for a few hours. I hope it will be ready for testing in a few hours thanks

Comment: Actually the problem was in the live feed, thank you for your comment Cheerz